# Rewrite rule not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm breaking my head in redirecting a few page from my old asp website to my new php website.

For example, I want to redirect permanently the following 2 pages from my asp website to my php website

1) http://www.mywebsite.com/shopdisplayproducts.asp?id=11&cat=food&sortorder=mostrecent&page=1&pagesize=12

TO

http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=10_11

where 11 should be the link between old and new website to display the correct page.

2) shopexd.asp?id=3903&prod=food&vrnt=green&mrk=studio&cat=11

TO

index.php?route=product/product&path=10_11&product_id=3903

where the number 11 is the link between old and new url for the category and the number 3903 is the link for the product number

I have the following rewrite rule in my htaccess page for the first redirect, but it seems not be triggered. What is wrong? Please help.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shopdisplayproducts\.asp\?id=([0-9]+).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^shopdisplayproducts\.asp\?id=([0-9]+).*$ index.php?route=product/category&path=10_$1 [R=301,L]
```

I also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^shopdisplayproducts\.asp\?id=([0-9]+).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^shopdisplayproducts\.asp\?id=([0-9]+).*$ index.php?route=product/category&path=10_$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for any help
Sabko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `QUERY_STRING` variable in rule condition:

```
RewriteEngine On

# /shopexd.asp?id=3903&prod=food&vrnt=green&mrk=studio&cat=11 to
# /index.php?route=product/product&path=10_11&product_id=3903
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&.*&cat=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^shopexd\.asp$ /index.php?route=product/category&path=10_%2&product_id=%1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^shopdisplayproducts\.asp$ /index.php?route=product/category&path=10_%1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: @ Anubhava, thank you for your quick response! This is working properly! However, I have 1 other old asp url that need to be directed permanently and which could come into conflict with your proposition because the query_string also contains "id=..." in it:     http://www.mywebsite.com/shopexd.asp?id=3903&prod=food&vrnt=green&mrk=studio&cat=11      should be reverted to       http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=10_11&product_id=3903. The number 11 is the link between old and new url for the category and the number 3903 is the link for the product number....

Comment: @ Anubhave: I have updated my initial question. Your solution works correctly, only I had to change in the first rewrite rule "shopdisplayproducts" to "shopexd" ( I think you did overlook the fact that 1 page is redirected from shopexd and the other from shopdisplayproducts). Thanks a lot! SabKo

Comment: @ Anubhave: I also made a solution that seem to work based on your first proposal:     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/shopdisplayproducts\.asp$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^shopdisplayproducts\.asp$ /index.php?route=product/category&path=10_%1 [R=301,NC,L]     and     

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/shopexd\.asp$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^shopexd\.asp$ /index.php?route=product/product&path=10_11&product_id=%1 [R=301,NC,L]